# Code stops working after I add a new colunm to Table

Tags: php, mysql

The code below a member and guest counter . The code runs perfectly however when I add a simple column (online) to the table active_members the entire code stops working (apart from the active_guests as this a separate table)

I have looked tirelessly trying to catch anything that may be causing this  I have included the table screenshot below . I would to had add new column (online)that is a varchar to the table members_online and then query in the if SESSION below for that new column .

Why does the code stop working , Can somebody possible see the cause or solution?

As soon as i remove the online column is code runs perfect again .

$sqlt2 query below is the line I want to index the new online column .

[image]

```
include('..\db.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($dbsrvname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

 //declare variables
$guest_timeout = time() -1 * 60;
$member_timeout = time() -1 * 60;
$guest_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$time = time();

 // if the session is set PUTS THE USER IN MEMBERS TABLE
if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])){

    //if user is logged in

    $sqlt = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE  FROM active_guests WHERE guest_ip='".$guest_ip."'");



   **//I WANT TO ADD TO THE ONLINE COLUMN AND REPLACE A SIMPLE STRING INTO ONLINE**
    $sqlt2 = mysqli_query($con,"REPLACE INTO active_members VALUES ('".$_SESSION['CurrentUser']."','".$time."')");
    $name = $_SESSION['CurrentUser']  ;





}else{

    //if user not in a session PUTS THE USER IN GUESTS TABLE
    $sqlt3 = mysqli_query($con,"REPLACE INTO active_guests (guest_ip,time_visited)VALUES ('".$guest_ip."','".$time."')");



}

 //execute querys
$sqlt4 = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE  FROM  active_guest WHERE time_visited < ".$guest_timeout);
$sqlt5 = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE  FROM  active_members WHERE time_visited < ".$member_timeout);
$sqlt6 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT guest_ip FROM active_guests");
$sqlt7 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username FROM active_members");
$online_guests = mysqli_num_rows($sqlt6);
if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])){


$sqlt7 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username FROM active_members");

if($sqlt7->num_rows){
            while($row = $sqlt7->fetch_object())
            {
            echo '<pre>',$row->username,'</pre>' ;

            }
            //$result->free();
        }
}else{
    echo "Login  to see members-online list";

}
$online_members = mysqli_num_rows($sqlt7);


?>

 // display results
<div class="container">
<p>_________________________</p>
<p>online Guests : <?php echo $online_guests ; ?></p>
<p>online Members : <?php  echo $online_members ; ?></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Can the column online be null? If not he tries to insert a new line with the REPLACE INTO statements without filling the online column and fails

Comment: What exactly is meant under code not working? It fails with some error?

Comment: @MarvinFischer Thank you Sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set column "online"s "Default/Expression" to null, hopefully it'll will work!